# change select option after 2 seconds of page load

Tags: jquery

I have a select named select1, when the select1 changes few events are triggered.
I want to change the select1 option after 2 seconds of page loading, so that the other events be trigger.

I am able to change the select1 option after 2 seconds of page loading, but this change is not triggering .change(function)

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value="21">apple</option>
  <option value="22">orange</option>
  <option value="23">banana</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
         $('select[name="select1"]').val(23);
    }, 2000);
})
```

other events

```
$('select[name="select1"]').change(function(){
.......
})
```

Comment: You can do like this : `$('select[name="select1"]').val(23);`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This change is not firing the .change function

Comment: work fine https://jsfiddle.net/shivamanhar/g3r5kwdz/1/

Comment: From th jQuery Docu: Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using .val() for example, won't fire the event. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fire the change method explicitly. As val() method won't fire it.

After val() call the change method for the select box.

```
$('select[name="select1"]').val(23).change();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
           $('select[name="select1"]').val(23).change();
      }, 2000);
  })


$('select[name="select1"]').change(function(){
  console.log("Select dropdown value has been changed");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
  <option value="21">apple</option>
  <option value="22">orange</option>
  <option value="23">banana</option>
</select>
```